# Axios call on select/enter with Vue Multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, multi-select

I have a functioning Vue Multiselect where I'm using an axios call to fill the options from my database values. This works perfectly and allows me to choose from existing options or enter new options in order to create tags.

As it is, this works perfectly. But I need a way, if possible, to make another Axios call every time the user selects and option or hits the enter key to save a tag option. Is there a way to do this?

This is my first experience with Vue and I'm really not sure how feasible this is, but basically I'm just wondering how to make an axios call every time a tag is selected or entered with the enter key

```
<div id="tagApp">
  <multiselect
  label="tag_data"
  track-by="campaign_tag_id"
  v-model="value"
  :options="options"
  :multiple="true"
  :taggable="true"
  @tag="addTag"
  @search-change="val => read(val)"
  :preselect-first="false"
  :close-on-select="false" 
  :clear-on-select="true" 
  :preserve-search="true" 
  tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" 
  placeholder="Search or add a tag"
  ></multiselect>
</div>

new Vue({
      components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
      },
      el: "#tagApp",
      data() {
        return{
            value: [],
            loading: false,
            options: []
        }

      },
      methods: {
        read: function(val){
            //console.log('searched for', val);
          if (val) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.options = [];

            const self = this;
            console.log(val);

            axios.get('campaigns/search',{params: {query: val}})
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.options = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
            });

          } else {
            this.options = [];
          }
        },
        addTag(newTag) {
          const tag = {
            tag_data: newTag,
          };
          this.options.push(tag);
          this.value.push(tag);
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: What problems are you having? Should be simple.. on select make your call, or on tag add make your call. Same concept of how autocomplete works.

Comment: I think I know that I can put an axios call in the current addTag function after my this.value.push line, but I'm wondering about how to do it on select?

Comment: Add a `v-on:change` attribute to your multi select and make your call there

Comment: Ok so if I add the v-on:change and make a call to axios and then also have the axios call in the addTag function then whether they type and enter a new one or they select from the autocomplete list it will make the new axios call?

Answer (score 1):

Monitor @select event and trigger a function where your Axios call will happen.

```
<div id="tagApp">
  <multiselect
  ...
  @select= "callAxios"
  ...
  ></multiselect>
</div>
```

```
...

   methods: {
        callAxios: function(val){
            //your Axios call here
        },
        ...
   }

...
```